# Can't get random value with an empty range

Tags: swift, if-statement, random, numbers, is-empty

I have 2 random numbers and one of them connected to other. Below is my code:

```
func funcrandomNumber()
  {
    number = String(Int.random(in: 1..<100))
    randomLabel.text = number
  }

func funcrandomSubMathNumber()
  {
    if let number = randomLabel.text , !number.isEmpty
    {
       math2Number = String(Int.random(in: 1..<Int(number)!))
    }
    else
    {
       funcrandomNumber()
    }
  }
```

sometimes it works perfectly but sometimes it gets the error:

> Fatal error: Can't get random value with an empty range

How to check if **number** is not empty?

Comment: You should store the random numbers in `Int` variables, instead of converting them to strings and back.

Comment: Don't name the methods as `func...`. It is already understood that it is a method when you use `()` to call it.

Comment: You shouldn't use a label to pass your data around. Keep the original data source used to set the label's text property.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `if` to

```
if let numberText = randomLabel.text, let number = Int(numberText), number > 1 {
    math2Number = String(Int.random(in: 1..<number))
}
```

Comment: Alternatively one can create the first random number with a minimal value of `2` ...